# Simple solution to integrate PayPal on ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

There are many solutions/products that PayPal provides for websites to integrate with PayPal payment. I would like to know what's the simplest or easiest solution to integrate PayPal into ASP.NET MVC web applications. Which solution I should use? It would be helpful if someone who had the done this before can share his or her experience. Thanks.

Comment: Is a 45 minute msft video too long? ;) http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-22-restructuring-rerouting-and-paypal

Comment: 45 minutes?! I will definitely check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Recently I implemented a PayPal 'Buy Now' button in a ASP.NET MVC Razor view. In the end the button is just a HTML form that is posted to the PayPal website. However, it took me some time to find out which hidden form fields were required, and which optional fields I could also use to further configure the payment process. I have published my experiences on my blog: http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.com/2012/01/single-item-paypal-buttons-and.html. There you will also find the source code for an MVC Html helper method that makes rendering single-item PayPal buttons less work.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating PayPal with MVC is not your issue.  Integrating your ecommerce checkout process is the hard part.  PayPal has a very nice pre-packaged assembly you just need to reference and your basically done.

My main point is that your technology stack isn't what you should be focusing on here.  Instead learn the PayPal API and how it fits into your existing codebase.

Comment: I guess I didn't phrase my question correctly. I was just wondering which product or API I should use since PayPal offer many different solutions such as Adaptive Payment API, Button Manager API, Express Checkout, etc. I was looking for a quick overview from developers like you who already have experience with PayPal APIs. Thanks.