# PayPal API with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

Is it the paypal API compatible with asp.net MVC? 
Does anyone know of any expamples of how to implement it?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple solution to integrate PayPal on ASP.NET MVC site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029624/simple-solution-to-integrate-paypal-on-asp-net-mvc-site)

Comment: @Lucero: that question is not marked as answered and there's a better response in a comment than in an answer :)

Comment: @Lorenzo, true, but it would still make sense to have those questions merged. They are about the same thing.

Comment: @Lucero: I completely agree with you. the problem is caused primarily from people that does not mark questions as answered. This make a question and its answers not helpful for others because it does not confirm that answers are right.

Comment: @Lorenzo, right. I chose to mark them as duplicates because even if not enough votes are cast, it may be catched during one of the cleanup sessions and merged, which seems to be the thing to do (especially now that we have a good accepted answer ;-) )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

yes it is compatible.

Have a look at [MVC Storefront Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-1-architectural-discussion-and-overview) videos.

[Episode 22](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-22-restructuring-rerouting-and-paypal) is dedicated to Paypal

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped. Even if that starter kit project has never reached it's 100%, you can find some code googling around that contains a Paypal controller you can start with. Regards

Comment: Here is the [code](http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/18861). And [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront) you'll find the Rob Conery blog posts that describes all the Storefront application

Comment: This answer needs to be updated. The example given here is for the old API.

Answer (score 6):

Recently I implemented a PayPal 'Buy Now' button in a ASP.NET MVC Razor view. In the end the button is just a HTML form that is posted to the PayPal website. However, it took me some time to find out which hidden form fields were required, and which optional fields I could also use to further configure the payment process. I have published my experiences on my blog: http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.com/2012/01/single-item-paypal-buttons-and.html.
There you will also find the source code for an MVC Html helper method that makes rendering single-item PayPal buttons less work.

Answer (score 5):

> **Source:** [Paypal add to cart multiple items form with discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840611/paypal-add-to-cart-multiple-items-form-with-discount/12936117#12936117)

I have successfully integrated the PayPal express checkout with shopping cart in to one of my Asp.net MVC projects with discount codes, shipping charges etc.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this site. http://www.arunrana.net/2012/01/paypal-integration-in-mvc3-and-razor.html 
It is specifically designed for MVC3 with Razor!