# How to redirect to paypal page on register button click using asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

When the user click on the register button on asp.net mvc 3 i need to redirect to the paypal payment page and i need to integrate the pay pal page with my mvc project how can i do that.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Did you google the question?

[Simple solution to integrate PayPal on ASP.NET MVC site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029624/simple-solution-to-integrate-paypal-on-asp-net-mvc-site)

[PayPal API with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494745/paypal-api-with-asp-net-mvc)

http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/paypal-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx